# I created a new C program and designated its workspace but it says that launch.json is not present. What does that mean?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I created a new folder in Visual Studio Code and designated its workspace, but it shows that Launch.Json is not present. I have worked in Python before but it never asked me for any `.json` file. Can someone please explain to me how this works?

My goal is to write a "hello world" program.

Comment: If you do it the other way around, it will configure most things for your. First, install the vscode C/C++ tools extension. (ms store or download the .vsix from github). Now, without touching vscode (1) create the folder you want to work in and (2) create the file `hello.c` in it. The contents can simply be the following lines `#include <stdio.h>` then `int main (void) {` then `puts ("Hello World!");` and finally `}`. Save the file. Now open vscode and chose `File -> Open Folder` and navigate to your new folder. Open it and vscode will ask you to choose the compiler. Now you can click `Build`

Comment: As an aside, there is a learning curve to using an IDE. A drawback to vscode is there are thousands of configuration options. It will take you 100-times longer to learn vscode than it will to simply build short C programs from the command line. But, that learning to use vscode provides many niceties that are very helpful when dealing with large projects, tens or hundreds of source files and tens of thousands of lines of code. That's what IDEs were created for, to help with complex projects. But, once you make friends with vscode, it is a very nice IDE.

Comment: with Python I always work with launch configs in `launch.json` or I use Python Interactive, read the VSC doc pages for the language you use

Answer (score 1):

`launch.json` is used for debugging. Unlike Python, C is a compiled language. So, you can use `vscode` as a text editor to write your code, and use a compiler (MSVC or MinGW on Windows, `gcc` on Linux, `clang` on macOS) to compile the source code into an executable that you can then run. The workflow is simply different for C compared to Python.

Assuming you are on Linux (I would recommend you install WSL - Windows Subsystem for Linux - if you are on Windows for C stuff), it would go as follows:

In `vscode`, create `test.c`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Then, open an integrated terminal in `vscode`: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>.

In the integrated terminal, use `gcc test.c -o test.out` to compile the source code into `test.out` executable.

Execute `./test.out` to run the executable.

Comment: Why use `(int argc, char **argv)` when you ignore those parameters?  It would be more sensible to use `(void)`.  It avoids warnings about unused variables when you set the warnings to be fussy.

Comment: `launch.json` is used for compile and run/debug the program, why type a lot of stuff in the terminal if VSC can do it for you